# WPF Grid: Dynamically Expand Border to Fill Space with Minimum Width Constraint

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working with a WPF Grid layout and want to create a horizontal border that expands to take up remaining space but also respects a minimum width. Here's my current code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="20" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="20" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Border 
       Grid.Column="0"
       MinWidth="20"
       Width="200"
       MaxWidth="200"
       Height="2"
       Margin="8,16,8,0"
       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Background="Red" >
   </Border>
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="" Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
   <Border 
       Grid.Column="2"
       Height="2"
       Margin="8,16,8,0"
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Background="Red" >
   </Border>
</Grid>
```

If the `TextBlock` got wider or tighter (becomes smaller), I want the `Border` to dynamically adjust so that it fills the remaining space to the right of the `TextBlock`. Also, the `Border` should not disappear when the `TextBlock` is too wide, it must maintain a minimum width of 20 pixels. Despite trying different width settings like `*`, `Auto`, and `5*` for the `TextBlock` and `2*` or `MinWidth` for the `Border`, but I haven't achieved the desired outcome. The `Border` either disappears or leaves an unfilled space.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, it must have a fixed width, maybe not 200, but It should be fixed.

Comment: I think you will need to set MaxWidth of TextBlock in order to focibly limit its width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set MaxWidth of the TextBlock in order to limit its width in any case. An easy workaround for this is to use a dummy element.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0"
            Width="200"
            Height="2"
            Margin="8,16,8,0"
            Background="Red"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          x:Name="Dummy"
          Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=Dummy, Path=ActualWidth}"
               Text="Sample"
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
               Background="Red"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="2"
            Height="2"
            Margin="8,16,8,0"
            Background="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I can't set the MinWidth of the right border with this solution, but this is almost the solution I need

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you could let the `Border` fill a `DockPanel`:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border 
               Grid.Column="0"
               MinWidth="20"
               Width="200"
               MaxWidth="200"
               Height="20"
               Margin="8,16,8,0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Background="Red" >
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="" Background="Red" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
    </Grid>

    <Border 
               DockPanel.Dock="Right"
               Height="20"
               MinWidth="20"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Background="Green" >
    </Border>

</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Not really, the Border doesn't respect its 20 pixel minimum width.
If the window is too tight, the TextBlock should become smaller and the Border on the right should maintain its minimum width of 20 pixels